# Jest: How to test get descriptor of Object

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test object and return his descriptors using jest. In my case the object contains get function. I believe my syntax is wrong here:

```
get: function number() {
    return this.x;
},
```

Any ideas how to fix it? 
Here the example:

```
let obj = {
    x: 10,
    get number() {
        return this.x;
    },
};

test('Return property descriptors of obj', () => {
    expect(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)).toMatchObject({
        x: {
            value: 10,
            writable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        },
        number: {
            get: function number() {
                return this.x;
            },
            set: undefined,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
});
```

And result:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a semi colon after get in the obj variable. So it will be get: function number(){} instead of get function number (),

Comment: let obj = {
    x: 10,
    get: number() {
        return this.x;
    },
};

Comment: not sure if it's right. "get" is getter here

Comment: `get: function number() {` is not the same function that is used in the object, hence the error. You may want to use `expect.any(Function)`.

Comment: number: {
            get: function number() {
                return this.x;
            },
            set: undefined,
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        }

Comment: Yeah it just seems like a naming thing

Comment: One is a key with get that returns the function number and one is a getter method number

Comment: @EstusFlask' yeah right the function is not the same. Could you please help me with syntax because I'm not sure about expect.any(Function)?

Comment: It's `get: expect.any(Function)` instead of `get: function number()`. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect

Comment: @GrantHerman Yes, my syntax was wrong

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assertion fails because `get: function number() {...}` isn't the same function as in the descriptor, `function number() {} !== function number() {}`.

It should be asserted to be any function with:

```
    ...
    number: {
        get: expect.any(Function),
        set: undefined,
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
    ...
```